# Get ASTER full bands file

Tags: remote-sensing, download, aster

I am having some problems on downloading ASTER data.
When I download a Landsat-8 scene, it cames with the full bands on it (14 band files), an metadata file and a quality file.

I need to download ASTER data, with all ASTER bands on it. 
I have tried to download ASTER_L1T_xxxx.hdf, but it only gives me 8 bands as per image below:

[image]

I have used Glovis (https://glovis.usgs.gov/) to download the image since it seems to be easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use NASA earthdata website for aster data. what is the date of your data?
It seems you are missing the SWIR bands because they are not avialible since 2008.
https://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/swir-alert.asp

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend downloading ASTER imagery from [Earth Explorer](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/). They deliver [ASTER Level 1T products](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/node/1091).

[image]

Comment: But the problem remains the same. I am unable to find a scene with all 14 bands available. The best I found was a scene with 13 bands and 1 missing. Perhaps I am missin something on working with ASTER data?

Comment: @pmatos Are you downloading both the thermal and standard product?

Comment: I have downloaded the Standard Product. Should I have to download the thermal (tif) file also?

Comment: tested with a scene with 7 unavailable bands (from band 3B to band 9), according to EarthExplorer scene information. Also downloaded the Thermal (tif) file. The result on ENVI: The standard file (hdf), shows 8 bands (from 10 to 14 and from 1 to 3N). Added the Thermal tif file and get 3 additional bands. The total bands equals 11 bands.